# UL Bullet style alignment

Tags: html, css

I am not able to figure out how to get this ul dropdown to align with the rest of my menu.

I have deleted the [Bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(typography))  from my ul dropdown, but my ul dropdown keeps it's position (*I suspected the ul dropdown to go all the way to the left side of the page if I did that*).

I have tried to style this ul dropdown to align with the rest of my menu but I am not able to figure this out.

I have set the `margin` and `padding` both to `0` which results to the dropdown being all the way to the left of my page (*as seen in the snippet*).

Changing the values of the `margin` and `padding` either *1* puts it to the left side of the screen or *2* puts it back in the position it originally had.

```js
 $('ul li.dropdown').hover(function() {
 
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-feJI7QwhOS+hwpX2zkaeJQjeiwlhOP+SdQDqhgvvo1DsjtiSQByFdThsxO669S2D" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- this uses list-style-type: none; which results in not having a bullet ( my goal) but not aligning to the other links correctly-->

<div class="w3-bar-block">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i>  Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  link 2</a>
   <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>  DropdownHeader</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">sub4</a></li>
     </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>


<!-- this uses list-style-type: none; padding: 0; and margin-0; which results in not having a bullet ( my goal) but not aligning to the other links correctly either. Does not matter what you change padding and margin to it will either stay to the left side of the screen or jump back to *original postion*-->

<div class="w3-bar-block">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i>  Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  link 2</a>
   <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin-0;">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i>  DropdownHeader</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">sub4</a></li>
     </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like you need to inline the elements that are the children of the root element in this element structure.
You could achieve this with the following CSS ...

.w3-bar-block > * { display: inline-block; }

... however, if all of this menu structure is your menu then you may find it simpler to standardise your markup like this ...

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li>
      <a>DropdownHeader</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">sub4</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then use css like this ...

```
.menu      { list-style-type: none; }
.menu > li { 
   vertical-align: top; 
   display: inline-block; 
   padding: 5px;
   background: #CCC;
}

.menu li > ul         { display: none; }
.menu li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

Here's a js fiddle that shows how it works ...

https://jsfiddle.net/sgh0tLv0/9/

... as per what i think you are asking, hover over your drop down header to open the sub menu it contains.

Assuming the menu is a "vertical" menu and not a horizontal one the following html and css will achieve the same result ...

html:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li>
      <a>DropdownHeader</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">sub4</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.menu > li { 
   vertical-align: top;  
   padding: 5px;
   background: #CCC;
}

.menu li > ul         { display: none; }
.menu li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

...

Using your HTML structure (which I would not recommend though) you could achieve this by doing the following ...

add menu class to the div at the root ...

```
<div class="w3-bar-block menu">
```

... then add the following CSS (in addition to the menu css above) ...

```
.w3-bar-block > * { display: block; margin: 10px; }
.w3-bar-block > ul { margin-left: -30px; }
.w3-bar-block > ul > li { margin-left: 0; }
```

Updated fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/sgh0tLv0/19/